# Python mock a cached method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that caches a method:

```
class Foo:

   def __init__(self, package: str):
      self.is_installed = functools.lru_cache()(
        self.is_installed)

   def is_installed():
       #implementation here
```

And code that calls the method by looping on the instances of the class

```
try:
  if Foo('package').is_installed():
except Exception as e:
  print('Could not install')
else:
  print('Installed properly')
```

I am trying to test this code by mocking the `is_installed` method to throw an exception.

```
@patch.object(Foo, 'is_installed')
def test_exception_installing_bear(self, mock_method):
    mock_method.side_effect = Exception('Something bad')
    # code to assert 'could not install' in stdout
```

But it does not work. The exception is not thrown and the assertion fails. On the other hand the output shows that it `installed properly`. I think it has something to be cached. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> see document

[unittest.TestCase.assertRaises](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

> Alternative

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception):
    mock_args = {'side_effect': Exception}
    with mock.patch('foo.Foo.is_installed', **mock_args):
         Foo.is_installed
```